# run jar file in command prompt output in .txt

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, output

Here are 2 files I use to start/stop my Jar application.

**Start.bat**: `start "app_test" java -jar application-test-1.2.0.jar %*> log.txt`
**Stop.bat**: `TASKKILL /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq app_test`

When I run my app, the output is not redirected to log.txt.
I don't understand why, anybody have an idea ?

Comment: are there any errors produces from the call?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `start` in your script, then it should work.

**Start.bat**: `java -jar application-test-1.2.0.jar %* > log.txt`

Tested it on Windows XP SP3 and Java 1.6.0_31 and it wrote all Java output to the denoted file.

Answer (score 0):

in command prompt if you are using windows,

C:> something.bat > console_output.txt